# How to query file database respone of format NWC or IFC?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

Hi team Autodesk Forge .
I have a question, I need query to get data from navisworks with file `respone.sdb` from ASP, but problem is external_id saved in table `_objects_id` when I check is look can't understand. Can I know how to query it and what is meaning of data like `0/0/0/4/0/0/0/0/1` ?
My case is I want query data from Navisworks file exported from Revit and mapping data with Revit.
If can, can give me with one example how to query and mapping with Revit data use ElementId of UniqueId ?

Preview :

[image]

Any help is appreciated !

I expecting I can understand how to query data of database provide by ASP after translate file with format IFC and NWC

Comment: This is an id that represents the hierarchy sequence of the object in the model tree. If your source model is IFC, you may try to check the object properties which should contain one id called IFCGuid, by which you could also find them in properties with APS.